# es6 syntax error react js build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build my project

I wrote this code to build my project  `npm run build`
but i got this errors:

```
Hash: 9e32da691bd77c2f4321
Version: webpack 4.6.0
Time: 10303ms
Built at: 2018-07-03 16:31:00
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
  [9] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js + 30 modules 75.7 KiB {0} [built]
      |    31 modules
 [40] ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js + 23 modules 43 KiB {0} [built]
      |    24 modules
 [42] ./src/public/appStyle.css 1.1 KiB {0} [built]
[106] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./src/public/bootstrap.min.css 532 KiB {0} [built]
[107] ./src/public/bootstrap.min.css 1.11 KiB {0} [built]
[115] ./src/public/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2 182 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[116] ./src/public/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg 247 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[117] ./src/public/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf 182 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[120] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./src/public/css/fontawesome-all.css 198 KiB {0} [built]
[121] ./src/public/css/fontawesome-all.css 1.13 KiB {0} [built]
[123] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./src/public/style.css 60.6 KiB {0} [built]
[124] ./src/public/style.css 1.09 KiB {0} [built]
[129] ./src/reducers/index.js 396 bytes {0} [built]
[131] ./src/store.js 384 bytes {0} [built]
[143] ./src/index.js 815 bytes {0} [built]
    + 130 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/components/WebApp/Routes/Register/Main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (106:14)

  104 |           return {
  105 |             date : {
> 106 |               ...prevState.date,
      |               ^
  107 |               day : {
  108 |                 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30
  109 |               }

 @ ./src/components/WebApp/Routes/Register/Register.js 21:12-29
 @ ./src/components/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/components/WebApp/Routes/Search/MainCategories.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (147:10)

  145 |       return {
  146 |         elements : {
> 147 |           ...prevState.elements,
      |           ^
  148 |           [status] : {
  149 |             id : id,
  150 |             name : name

 @ ./src/components/WebApp/Routes/Search/SearchCategories.js 17:22-49
 @ ./src/components/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/components/OnePage/OnePage.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:13)

  14 |
  15 |
> 16 |   finishLoad = (isLoad) => {
     |              ^
  17 |     this.setState({ isLoad: isLoad })
  18 |     }
  19 |

 @ ./src/components/App.js 13:15-43
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/components/WebApp/Routes/Support/Main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:18)

  2 | import send from './../../../../public/img/send.svg'
  3 | export default class Main extends Component{
> 4 |   continueMessage = () => {
    |                   ^
  5 |     this.refs.inputBox.focus();
  6 |   }
  7 |   render(){

 @ ./src/components/WebApp/Routes/Support/Support.js 17:12-29
 @ ./src/components/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/public/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
| <!--
| Font Awesome Free 5.0.6 by @fontawesome - http://fontawesome.com
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./src/public/css/fontawesome-all.css 7:70780-70822
 @ ./src/public/css/fontawesome-all.css
 @ ./src/index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [0] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html 664 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! sevenapp@0.1.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sevenapp@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mohammadmehdi/.npm/_logs/2018-07-03T12_01_00_879Z-debug.log
```

I'm using npm version 6.0.1 and webpack version 4.

My Webpack Config is:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./public/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                            sourceMap: true,
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin]
};
```

The rest of my files are below.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sevenapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rc-pagination": "^1.16.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-countup": "^3.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-paginate": "^5.2.3",
    "react-player": "^1.6.4",
    "react-popup": "^0.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "description": ":D",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "author": "MM",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
    ]
}
```

what is my wrong?

my OS is macOS highSierra version 10.13.3 
node js version 10
react version 16.2

Comment: Object spreading is not available in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

The rest/spread operators (`...`) are currently not in Babel by default, so you need at least the [stage 3 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-3) (or the [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread) by itself) for it to work properly:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @MohammadMehdi That's frustrating. What error did you get now?